# CSS transitions have a delay when iterating through properties in webkit browsers

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

Webkit browsers seem to have a delay when iterating through animated properties, but Firefox doesn't. I prefer the way Firefox handles this but I can't get the same behavior in Chrome or Safari.

Firefox works:

[image: Firefox Works]

Chrome doesn't:

[image: Chrome Doesn't]

I'm using Autoprefixer, so I don't think it's vendor prefixes.

[Here is a Codepen with Jade and SCSS.](http://codepen.io/dustindowell22/pen/YPzQmO)

This is the compiled HTML and CSS:

```css
* {
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 0.25s;
}
body {
  color: #000;
}
.blog-tile {
  background-color: #7f7f7f;
  transition: all 0.25s;
}
.blog-tile:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<section class="blog">
  <div class="center">
    <div class="grid-blog-tile-list">
      <div class="col-blog-tile-list">
        <div class="blog-tile">
          <div class="root">
            <h1 class="blog-title"><a href="#">Heading 1</a></h1>
            <h2 class="blog-date">October 2, 2014</h2>
            <p>Words might happen here. Words might happen here. Words might happen here. Words might happen here. Words might happen here. Words might happen here.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- more html -->

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

How can I get this behavior with CSS?

Comment: Try using the proper vendor prefixes i.e. `-webkit-transition`, `-moz-transition`, etc. Uncertain if that's the issue though.

Comment: @aug I'm using Autoprefixer. They're there. I should have mentioned that.

Comment: @misterManSam Yes, here it is: 
http://codepen.io/dustindowell22/pen/YPzQmO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by applying the transition to the universal selector (`*`). Apply the transition to `.blog-tile` and there is no problem.

Use the `transition` property more selectively.

**Note:** [The transition property is very well supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions) without prefixes. A lot of the prefixes added by Autoprefixer for `transition` are adding unnecessary bulk to your compiled CSS.

### Working Example

Also with SCSS / Jade [in Codepen](http://codepen.io/misterManSam/pen/azbydE)

```css
body {
  color: #000;
}
.blog-tile {
  background-color: #7f7f7f;
  transition: all 0.25s;
}
.blog-tile:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<section class="blog">
  <div class="center">
    <div class="grid-blog-tile-list">
      <div class="col-blog-tile-list">
        <div class="blog-tile">
          <div class="root">
            <h1 class="blog-title"><a href="#">Heading 1</a></h1>
            <h2 class="blog-date">October 2, 2014</h2>
            <p>Words might happen here. Words might happen here. Words might happen here. Words might happen here. Words might happen here. Words might happen here.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```